# Android Studio 2.0 - preview 6 with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I am using android Studio 2.0 preview 6 , I faced this problem when i am trayning to build my application

Error:(9, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:

The project 'RingButton' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

This is build.gradle file

Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5'
    compile 'com.victor.ringbutton:lib:1.0.1'

     NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
     in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
}

 allprojects {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
 }
}

 task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any Help

Comment: Shouldn't the `compile 'com.victor.ringbutton:lib:1.0.1'` declaration be in the module's build.gradle? I don't know if that would solve your problem, but libraries _shouldn't_ be declared in the project build.gradle. There is a note right there too.

Answer (score 0):

open your app:build.gradle file and put your dependencies(compile 'com.victor.ringbutton:lib:1.0.1') in there  if they are external dependencies not in this file which belong to gradle only . 
you can find app:build.gradle in project structure by just changing from android to project view then click your project and then app and you got it build.gradle .see image attached[image]